# changed settings in python IDLE

Tags: python

I tried to change the window size in IDLE but now IDLE won't launch. I have tried deleting it, removing it from trash and reinstalling both 3.5 and 2.7 again but still have the same problem. Command/option/escape indicates it hasn't launched and is not in the background.

The screen size when this started was originally 80 x 80 pixels but I changed it to 88800 x 44480 by accident (couldn't type in the box for some reason). I think this has caused the issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try this: do a complete uninstall. Run CCleaner or similar registry cleanup. Reboot, Install again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Windows, there is a hidden folder in your user folder

```
C:\Users\username\.idlerc\config-main.cfg
```

In this file, you can edit the size of the IDLE window, under the `[EditorWindow]` header. See [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Mac/IDLE/config-main.def) for a sample config file. Or you can just delete the `width` and `height` entries, and it should go back to default.